# TimThumb use with pictures from non public folder or virtual folder

Tags: php, image-resizing

I am using the TimThumb script (http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/). My images links are generated like this: `http://website.com/pics/nature/animals/bear.png` and this works great but I can't seem to use TimThumb like this: `http://website.com/resize.php?src=http://website.com/pics/nature/animals/bear.png&h=150&w=150`, it says `Could not find the internal image you specified`. I believe this is because my images are brought from a folder by slug names (`bear.png`). The folder's images are named by the ID of the image so there is no bear.png on the server, my application is using slugs to search the DB and bring up the real name of the picture but it loads the image upon this link: `http://website.com/pics/nature/animals/bear.png`. If I give my resize.php script a link from flickr it works great.

BTW, resize.php is the actual TimThumb script.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use a local path, enter the full URL for timthumb just like you did with flickr